# how to url split and use the second element as a new url

Tags: html, web, redirect, split, webflow

I try to split url with '?' and use the second element on html

example:

```
https://url/page?google.com
```

the output I want to receive is: `google.com`

and redirect the page to the output, I'm using webflow so if anyone can help with a full script it will be amazing.

I tried:

```
window.location.replace(id="new_url");
let url = window.location;
const array = url.split("?");
document.getElementById("new_url").innerHTML = array[1];
```

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.replace(id="new_url");` is not valid syntax.
`window.location.replace(new_url);` where new_url contained a valid URL would instantly change the page and ignore all other script after it.

I assume you can use the URL api?

Note
your parameter is non-standard
you need to add protocol (https://) to go to the URL

Here is a complicated version, but using a standard tool

```js
const urlString = "https://url/page?google.com"
const url = new URL(urlString)
console.log(url.toString())
const firstSearchKey = [...url.searchParams.entries()][0][0]; // normally parameter=value
console.log(firstSearchKey)
location.replace(`https://${firstSearchKey}`)
```

Here is a simpler version

```js
const urlString = "https://url/page?google.com"
const [origin,passedUrl] = urlString.split("?");
location.replace(`https://${passedUrl}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const url = window.location.search.split("?")[1]
window.location.href = url
```

Comment: This is already answered, but you need the protocol

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url = "https://url/page?google.com"
const regex = /\?(.*)/;
let res = regex.exec(url)
console.log(res[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```js
const inputUrl = window.location.href // ex. https://url/page?google.com
const splitUrl = inputUrl.split("?") // = ["https://url/page", "google.com"]
const targetUrl = splitUrl[1] // = "google.com"
window.location.href = targetUrl // sets current window URL to google.com
```